# What is the difference between OWASP PHPSEC and PHP-ESAPI?

Tags: web-application, php

On the surface it looks like both libraries are designed to preform the same functionality with similar "drop-in" capabilities. Are there differences that I need to take into account when making a decision about which to use? If so, what are they?

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Security_Project
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *not* use ESAPI-PHP.   It's a port of the Java ESAPI framework, (which has had its own issues, but soldiers on, more or less, mostly less) but the PHP port has been dead for a considerable amount of time now.  I wouldn't trust it as far as I could throw it.

I can't speak authoritatively to the PHP Security Project, but at a glance, the PHP Security Project may be in a similar state (their project page and site announces their upcoming participation in AppSecUSA 2013, which happened over a year ago) but at least it was a native PHP framework designed for PHP, so there may still be use to be had from it.  It's potentially worth researching, at minimum.